# The length arc of parabola

Tags: calculus, integration, conic-sections

Find the length of the arc of the parabola $y^2=4x$ from $x=0$ to $x=4$.

In the manual solution is
$2\sqrt{5}+\ln(2+\sqrt{5}).$

My answer is

$\displaystyle 2\int_0^4 \! \sqrt{1+\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}} \, \mathrm{d}x$

$\displaystyle 2\int_0^4 \! \sqrt{1+\frac{y^2}{4}} \, \mathrm{d}x$

$\displaystyle 2\int_0^4 \! \sqrt{4+y^2} \, \mathrm{d}x= 4 \sqrt{5}+2\ln(2+\sqrt{5})$

But my answer is $4 \sqrt{5}+2\ln(2+\sqrt{5})$
As I doubled the length, Do we need to double the arc length?

Comment: May be you did some mistake, or may be the manual solution is wrong? Why don't you show your calculation so that we can have a look?

Comment: Note that $y=2\sqrt x$ if you take only the positive square root. Then, $y^\prime=x^{-1/2}$ and $s=\int_0^4\sqrt{1+1/x} dx=2\sqrt 5+\log(2+\sqrt 5)$.

Comment: I updated the post and added my solution. I took the positive square root and twice it as the graph of parabola has one length above the x axis and another below the x axis

Comment: It seems pretty weird to describe the arc length of a non-function using a range of $x$ values. But if the exercise intended restricting attention to the first quadrant, then it should say so, or explicitly write $y=2\sqrt{x}$ as the function of interest. So, I'd consider the question poorly posed. If forced to choose, I might well have interpreted the exercise as you did, calculating the "doubled" arc length.

Comment: I did the calculations putting $\;y=2\sqrt x\;,\;\;x\ge0\;$ and then multiplying by two...and got exactly the same resutl as you did, after two substitutions and etc.

Comment: @Blue I think the question is pretty nicely posed: they ask for the length of that parabola. They didn't even mention "function" in the question. We can do as $\;y=2\sqrt x\,,\,\,\,x\ge0\;$ and then multiply by two. I see nothing weird in that.

Comment: @DonAntonio: *"I think the question is pretty nicely posed: the ask for the length of that parabola."* Tell that to the author of the manual's soln. :) ... As I wrote, I'm in favor of the "double-arc", but I maintain that the exercise could be phrased better. It *is* weird to use "from $x=0$ to $x=4$" to describe an arc that, *as a path*, goes "from $x=4$ to $x=0$ *and back* to $x=4$". You & I know the intention is "for $x\in[0,4]$", but it's not-unreasonable for someone to instinctively associate "from/to" with "start/end", requiring unnecessary re-(re?-)reading to alleviate any confusion.

Comment: The question might have been less-double-takedly-phrased by replacing "from" with "between"; as it stands, the manual's solution arbitrary choice of just one half of the parabola isn't justified.

Comment: @Blue Again, they are asking for the path described by the parabola when $\;x\;$ ranges between zero and $\;4\;$ ...which  I understand as "when the $\;x\,-$ variable ranges...". That's imo a perfectly well-asked, precise question. And when $\;x\;$ does you don't go from zero to 4 and back again. The geometric image is completely well defined: because of the $\;y^2\;$ term, you get two values for eack $\;0<x\le 4\;$ ... No need, as already mentioned, to think of functions at all. That may come later when trying to solve the problem.

Comment: @ryang I agree that the manual's solution isn't justified at all according to their own question. They should evaluate all the parabola's length or specify they only want the branch obtained when $\;y\ge0\;$ ...